# Zend_Log class not found when encrypting code with ZendGuard

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to lockdown some PHP with ZendGuard 5.5 for PHP5.3 and had this working fine with no issues under PHP 5.2. I can run the code fine unencrypted, but when I add the encryption it throws the following error:

**Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log' not found in ../app/code/local/MyModule/TestModule/Model/Mysql4/Setup.php on line 0**

If I start replacing troubled files with unencrypted versions the error moves to other encrypted files in the module.

The following is code that is put at the top of every PHP file to enable license support. *This code is actually working for another new module that was recently programmed.*

```
if(zend_loader_file_encoded()) {

    if(!zend_loader_enabled() || !zend_get_id()) {

        exit('<strong>Error:</strong> The Zend Optimizer loader is not enabled! <br /><br />To enable it, please modify the following in your php.ini:  zend_optimizer.enable_loader = on.');
                                                }

            else if(!zend_loader_file_licensed()){
                $licensePath = Mage::getModuleDir('etc', 'MyModule_TestModule'). DS . 'license' . DS . 'license.zl';
                    if(!file_exists($licensePath)) {
                        exit("<strong>Error:</strong> No license file was found. Your license file should be located in: $licensePath. <br /><br />If you do not have a license, you need to obtain one from the Dev Team by contacting: <a href=\"mailto:devteam@site.com\">devteam@site.com</a>.");
                                               } 

if(!zend_loader_install_license($licensePath)) {
exit('<strong>Error:</strong> An error occurred while loading your license file. Please contact support at <a href="mailto:devteam@site.com">devteam@site.com</a>.');
                       }
                    }
                }
```

I've searched low and high and can't figure this one out for the life of me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar 'class not found' error after encoding some code with ZendGuard.

Re-encoding with the obfuscation of variable, function, and class names disabled fixed the problem for me.

It seems the ZendGuard encoder is not able to handle some types of unusual but legal PHP syntax.